# «повести бровью» vs. «повести бровями»

Tags: выражения

С английским выражением «he raised his eyebrow**s** / he didn't even raise his eyebrow**s**» обязательно следует, строго говоря, поставить существительное «eyebrows» во множественное число.

С точки зрения логики и имеет больший смысл повести обеими бровями с удивлением при виде какого-то шокирующего события. Тогда тем более интересно, наоборот ли обычно бывает в русском языке:

> напр. «он и **бровью** не повел» вм. «он и **бровями** не повел»

Или, возможно, единственное «бровью» употребляется только в отрицательном предложении, чтобы подчеркнуть, что он даже не потрудился пошевелить единой бровью?

Викисловарь, точнее английская [Википедия](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8#Russian), показывает обе версии, не упоминая о возможной разнице в использовании.

Answer (score 3):

В английском единственное число тоже употребляется:

> I led him through into the dining-room, and when he saw the
>   nearly-eaten steak on a plate the dear man did not even **raise an
>   eyebrow**.Barnard, Robert THE DISPOSAL OF THE LIVING (2002)

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/raise-an-eyebrow

В русском выражении "*и бровью не повёл*" с отрицанием - да, есть усилительный оттенок "*даже одной*". Похожий пример из английской книжки: '*do not say a thing or even **move an eyebrow***'.

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=Z3QgAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA57&img=1&pgis=1&dq=even-move-an-eyebrow&sig=ACfU3U35JUu8hq_nO9IsCgqTy4wtKBrSmA&edge=0

Answer (score 1):

Both singular and plural are possible, but the usage will be different:

1) Plural: (удивленно) поднять **брови** = raise the eyebrows (in surprise)

2) Singular: **бровью** не повести, **бровью** не пошевельнуть = not to bat an eyelid.

Please note that singular case is a set expression, so you shall just memorize it that way.